# QML: Change Text position of Checkable MenuItem

Tags: qt, qml, menuitem

currently I am trying to get into QML for a future software project. I got a small application running and wanted to make a checkable MenuItem. I looked through the [QtQuick2 Controls Customizing Guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html) and already changed the Indicator. Now is my problem that I want the Textposition of the checkable MenuItem to be the same as the non checkable MenuItem.

```
Menu {
id: viewMenu
y: parent.height
    MenuItem {
        text: qsTr("Switch Mode")
    }
    MenuItem {
        id: showSidebar
        checkable: true
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("Show Sidebar")
        leftPadding: 0
        indicator: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: 26
            implicitWidth: 26
            x: parent.width - 35
            y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
            radius: 3
            border.color: showSidebar.down ? "#17a81a" : "#a451a4"

            Rectangle {
                x: 6
                y: 6
                width: 14
                height: 14
                radius: 2
                color: showSidebar.down ? "#17a81a" : "#a451a4"
                visible: showSidebar.checked
            }

        }
        contentItem: Text {

            text: showSidebar.text
            font: showSidebar.font
            opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
            color: showSidebar.down ? "#17a81a" : "#a451a4"
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            rightPadding: showSidebar.indicator.width + showSidebar.spacing
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

I tried to change the x position in the contentItem: Text part but didn't work . Changing the padding didn't work either. I am using Qt 5.9 (cannot switch to 5.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the `leftPadding` and `horizontalAlignment` lines in your showSidebar `MenuItem`, and you should be good to go.

leftPadding will default to the same padding value as the other menu item, while horizontal alignment will default to Text.AlignLeft.

```
MenuItem {
    id: showSidebar
    checkable: true
    checked: true
    text: qsTr("Show Sidebar")
    // leftPadding: 0
    indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitHeight: 26
        implicitWidth: 26
        x: parent.width - 35
        y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
        radius: 3
        border.color: showSidebar.down ? "#17a81a" : "#a451a4"

        Rectangle {
            x: 6
            y: 6
            width: 14
            height: 14
            radius: 2
            color: showSidebar.down ? "#17a81a" : "#a451a4"
            visible: showSidebar.checked
        }

    }
    contentItem: Text {
        text: showSidebar.text
        font: showSidebar.font
        opacity: enabled ? 1.0 : 0.3
        color: showSidebar.down ? "#17a81a" : "#a451a4"
        // horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        rightPadding: showSidebar.indicator.width + showSidebar.spacing
    }
}
```